# Derived class inheritance from base class in different header issue

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm having what I think is a cyclic dependency issue in my code, but I'm unsure how to troubleshoot it at this point. Anyway, I've got a "Behavior" class in my Behavior.h header:

```
#ifndef BEHAVIOR_H
#define BEHAVIOR_H

#include <list>
#include "DllEntry.h"

class Bot;

//Draws directly from BTSK, copyright alexjc

enum Status {
BH_INVALID,
BH_SUCCESS,
BH_FAILURE,
BH_RUNNING,
BH_ABORTED,
};


///Behavior: Base class for actions, conditions, and composites.
class Behavior {

protected:
Status m_eStatus;
Bot* m_pBot;

public:
Behavior(Bot& b) : m_eStatus(BH_INVALID), m_pBot(&b) {}
virtual ~Behavior() {}

virtual void OnInitialize() {}
virtual Status Update() = 0;
virtual void OnTerminate(Status) {}

Status Tick();

void Reset();
void Abort();

bool IsTerminated() const;
bool IsRunning() const;
Status GetStatus() const;
};

#endif
```

And a set of HighLevelBehaviors in my HighLevelBehaviors.h header. These headers all inherit from the Behavior class:

```
#ifndef HIGHLEVELBEHAVIORS_H
#define HIGHLEVELBEHAVIORS_H

#include "Behavior.h"
#include "DllEntry.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////
//***Grab Healthpickup***/////////////////
//Selector: Finds health if health is low
//////////////////////////////////////////

class Bot;

///IsHealthLow: Condition node
//Return true if health is low
class IsHealthLow : public Behavior {

public:
IsHealthLow(Bot& b) : Behavior(b) {}
~IsHealthLow() {}

virtual void OnInitialize() {}
virtual Status Update();
virtual void OnTerminate(Status) {}
};


///FindClosestHealthPickup: Action node
//Return true if health a health pickup is found. Also
//sets a variable so that later Tasks can path to it.
// TODO Change to "FindClosestItem<"ITEM_CLASS">" so that we can it for multiple items.
// This will make it more modular.
class FindClosestHealthPickup : public Behavior {

public:
FindClosestHealthPickup(Bot& b) : Behavior(b) {}
~FindClosestHealthPickup() {}

virtual void OnInitialize() {}
virtual Status Update();
virtual void OnTerminate(Status) {}
};


///CreatePathToTarget: Action node
//Return true if path is successfully create
//Again, this can potentially be set up to reference different fields
//in the "Blackboard" data struct aka CreatePathToTarget(target="ENEMY")
//or CreatePathToTarget(target="HEALTH_PICKUP").
class CreatePathToHealthPickup : public Behavior {

public:
CreatePathToHealthPickup(Bot& b) : Behavior(b) {}
~CreatePathToHealthPickup() {}

virtual void OnInitialize();
virtual Status Update();
virtual void OnTerminate(Status) {}
};


///FollowPathToTarget: Action node
class FollowPathToHealthPickup : public Behavior {

public:
FollowPathToHealthPickup(Bot& b) : Behavior(b) {}
~FollowPathToHealthPickup() {}

virtual void OnInitialize();
virtual Status Update();
virtual void OnTerminate(Status);
};

#endif
```

The errors I'm receiving are:

```
highlevelbehaviors.h(20): error C2504: 'Behavior' : base class undefined
highlevelbehaviors.h(27): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Update'
highlevelbehaviors.h(27): error C2433: 'IsHealthLow::Status' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
highlevelbehaviors.h(27): warning C4183: 'Update': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
....
```

I was wondering if there was anything else I could do sans just combining the two headers so that the compiler can see the base class I'm trying to derive from. Is there maybe something having to do with scope? Also, I apologize for my random commenting conventions, I'm still trying to determine which one I like best. Thanks for any help!

One more thing: if need be I can include the .cpp files for these, as well as the Bot.h file, which **both Behavior.h and HighLevelBehaviors.h include** (bolded because I think this may be important but I'm unsure...).

Comment: What's in `bot.h`? Since you have a forward declaration of `Bot` and it doesn't look like the its definition is needed in the headers you can probably skip including it.

Comment: Please try to provide a [minimal example](http://www.sscce.org/) to ease analysis.

Comment: An observation, not an answer:  `#pragma once` and the include guard symbols are redundant.  You need one or the other.

Comment: Are you able to compile just the Behavior implementation file (like Behavior.cpp)?

Comment: One way to diagnose this type of problem is (temporarily!) to add `#pragma message("Begin include " __FILE__)` at the beginning of each file and `#pragma message("End Include " __FILE__)` at the end.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with your Behavior.h file. Are you sure you don't have duplicate header file name?

Comment: Also check if Bot.h and DllEntry.h headers have any errors.

Comment: @rockoder I attempted to compile Behavior.cpp on its own, and it gave me the compile errors for HighLevelBehaviors (!). I compiled HighLevelBotBehaviors.cpp and it was successful, and I compiled Bot.cpp and it was successful. Anyone know what this means?

Comment: @Tahlil As far as I can tell I've only got one Behavior.h file.

Comment: @gha.st Thanks for the tips. I had already pared off a lot of extra code that I thought wouldn't be necessary. I was hoping that it would be easy to follow as is.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I forward declared the Bot because I make reference to it in the constructor of the Behavior class.

Comment: But you also [needlessly] include the header file. If the header is not needed and the forward declaration is enough remove the inclusion of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some changes, my code now successfully compiles. Here's what I did:
As per @CaptainObvlious, I removed the #include "Bot.h" from the Behavior.h and HighLevelBehavior.h since I was already forward referencing the Bot class in both of them. This meant that I needed to move the include to the actual .cpp files, since they make reference to the classes variables and functions. Everything now compiles.

While I will mark this as the answer, I think it obviously means I need to reevaluate my current system's design, which I was going to do anyway. I appreciate everyone's help; I ended up not only fixing my problem but also learning some good stuff about #pragma. I will update the code with the changes.

Comment: You seem uneasy about this solution, but that's exactly the right way to solve the problem.  It is very common to have a class forward declared in a header and have the class's actual declaration included in the corresponding cpp file.